# What is the logic behind allowing only same Monad types to be concatenated with `>>` operator?

Tags: haskell, monads

Though it is okay to bind `IO [[Char]]` and `IO ()` but its not allowed to bind `Maybe` with `IO`. Can someone give an example how this relaxation would lead to a bad design? Why freedom in the polymorphic type of Monad is allowed though not the Monad itself?

Comment: You can only use operations that a typeclass instance actually supports. An instance of `Monad` only supplies `(>>=)  :: m a -> (  a -> m b) -> m b`, i.e. it restrictively requires the same `m` to be used throughout. If you can see some sensible meaning for there to be an arbitrary "bind over anything" operation, then by all means, you can specify it as a typeclass and create as many instances as you know how. A class like `(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> n b) -> n b`, while requiring nothing of the consumer, is almost impossible to sensibly satisfy for an implementer.

Comment: The theory behind the `Monad` type class requires `m` to be the same functor; this property is what makes it suitable as a basis for handling IO; you can't escape from `IO` by switching to a different type.

Comment: How would you bind `Maybe` with `IO`? An `IO` monad does *not* alters the state, it describes *how* to alter the state.

Comment: I can understand questions of the form "why would this alternate design be bad?"; it makes sense to wonder whether you have missed some important consideration and ask others to help you think of things you haven't. Nevertheless, I feel like the person asking such a question also has a burden to say what the alternate design is and why it would be good. I don't think you've described either of those things (what would binding a `Maybe` to an `IO` do? and why would that be good?).

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of good theoretical reasons, including "that's not what `Monad` is."  But let's step away from that for a moment and just look at the implementation details.

First off - `Monad` isn't magic.  It's just a standard type class.  Instances of `Monad` only get created when someone writes one.

Writing that instance is what defines how `(>>)` works.  Usually it's done implicitly through the default definition in terms of `(>>=)`, but that just is evidence that `(>>=)` is the more general operator, and writing it requires making all the same decisions that writing `(>>)` would take.

If you had a different operator that worked on more general types, you have to answer two questions.  First, what would the types be?  Second, how would you go about providing implementations?  It's really not clear what the desired types would be, from your question.  One of the following, I guess:

```
class Poly1 m n where
    (>>) :: m a -> n b -> m b

class Poly2 m n where
    (>>) :: m a -> n b -> n b

class Poly3 m n o | m n -> o where
    (>>) :: m a -> n b -> o b
```

All of them could be implemented.  But you lose two really important factors for using them practically.

1. You need to write an instance for every pair of types you plan to use together. This is a massively more complex undertaking than just an instance for each type. Something about `n` vs `n^2`.
2. You lose predictability.  What does the operation even *do*?  Here's where theory and practice intersect.  The theory behind `Monad` places a lot of restrictions on the operations.  Those restrictions are referred to as the "monad laws".  They are beyond the ability to verify in Haskell, but any `Monad` instance that doesn't obey them is considered to be buggy. The end result is that you quickly can build an intuition for what the `Monad` operations do and don't do.  You can use them without looking up the details of every type involved, because you know properties that they obey.  None of those possible classes I suggested give you any kind of assurances like that. You just have no idea what they do.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that I understand your question correctly, but it’s definitely possible to compose `Maybe` with `IO` or `[]` in the same sense that you can compose `IO` with `[]`.

For example, if you check the types in GHCI using `:t`,

```
getContents >>= return . lines
```

gives you an `IO [String]`. If you add

```
            >>= return . map Text.Read.readMaybe
```

you get a type of `IO [Maybe a]`, which is a composition of `IO`, `[]` and `Maybe`.  You could then pass it to

```
            >>= return . Data.Maybe.catMaybes
```

to flatten it to an `IO [a]`. Then you might pass the list of parsed valid input lines to a function that flattens it again and computes an output.

Putting this together, the program

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>=                    -- IO String
       return . lines >>=                 -- IO [String]
       return . map readMaybe >>=         -- IO [Maybe Int]
       return . catMaybes >>=             -- IO [Int]
       return . (sum :: [Int] -> Int) >>= -- IO Int
       print                              -- IO ()
```

with the input:

```
1

2
Ignore this!
3
```

prints `6`.

It would also be possible to work with an `IO (Maybe [String])`, a `Maybe [IO String]`, etc.

You can do this with `>>` as well. Contrived example: `getContents >> (return . Just) False` reads the input, ignores it, and gives you back an `IO (Maybe Bool)`.